# Stored Procedure Query that adds parameter value to table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a procedure that adds the parameter value to a different table.
From what I've read, I believe I am on the right track, but cant figure out where to go from here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addToNotificationTable @ID int
AS
SELECT * 
FROM Images
WHERE ID = @ID
```

I want to add the @ID parameter to a different table (NotificationTable). Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by adding Insert [table] (column).

Before, my query was only selecting a record in my table (Images) where ID matched the parameter. Now it takes that ID and adds it to another table (NotificationTable).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addToNotificationTable @ID int
AS
Insert NotificationTable (ID)
SELECT ID 
FROM Images
Where ID = @ID
```

Comment: Hi Vigs. Your answer would be a lot more complete if you explained how it differs from your question. What did you change and why?